# Symfony2 form collection -

Tags: forms, symfony, doctrine

I am building a gallery of images which must allow for tagging each image with keywords. To handle the tags, I'm using FPN/TagBundle (https://github.com/FabienPennequin/FPNTagBundle).

I've already built the form, using the following:

```php
// UserAlbumImageType.php

...
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
{
    $builder
        ->add('description', null, array('label' => 'Description'))
        //TODO: add tags
        ->add('tags', null, array(
            'label' => 'Tags',
            'mapped' => false,
            'required' => false,
            'attr' => array(
                'class' => 'tags',
            ),
        ))
        ->add('licenseType', 'entity', array(
            'label' => 'License',
            'class' => 'VoxCoreBundle:LicenseType',
        ))
        ->add('privacyType', null, array('label' => 'Privacy'))
        ;
}$builder
                ->add('images', 'collection', array(
                    'type' => new UserAlbumImageType(),
                    'label' => false,
                ))
            ;
            break;
...

// UserAlbumType.php

...
$builder
    ->add('images', 'collection', array(
        'type' => new UserAlbumImageType(),
        'label' => false,
    ))
    ;
    break;
...
```

As you can see, the tags property is NOT mapped. This is because I don't want to write the tags into a field in the database, but instead persist them to a central tag table. And that's where the problem lies.

When the form is submitted, I'm simply calling `$em->persist($userAlbum)` which then persists changes to the `UserAlbumImage` objects in the collection. At this time, I'd like to grab the tags that were submitted via the form, and set them using the tag manager. I'm unsure where to handle this. In a Doctrine postPersist listener? If so, I'll still need to save the tags to the entity at least temporarily, then parse them. Is there a better way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I were you, I'd follow (as I'm always trying to do) the MVC pattern with added repositories. I'd implement a `saveGallery` method in the repository for the gallery entity. This would get called from the controller (similar as mansolux recommended, but instead having the store functionality in the controller (bad practice, if you ask me), call the repository method for it). The method would receive all the submitted data. It would first store all the entities that need to be stored before the tags (gallery, images, whatnot). After that I'd get the tag repository:

```
$repo = $this->em->getRepository("FPNTagBundle:TagEntityName");
```

Now, the only thing left to do is to store the tags using this repository. You can add some sanity checks to make sure the tag bundle you're using actually exists, but that's something for you to decide.

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Why not in your controller :

```
// ...
$tags = $form->getData()->getTags();
foreach($tags as $tag) {
    $em->persist($tag);
}
// ...

$em->flush();
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. That would normally be fine, but unfortunately the FPNTagBundle requires the entity (in this case, UserAlbumImage) to be persisted before the tags can be saved: https://github.com/FabienPennequin/FPNTagBundle#using-tags